# print array elements in reverse order in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to print the elements of an array in reverse order, starting from the last element to the 0th element, when I dont know the list count, without using reverse function. Here is the input and output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl/
use warnings;
use strict;

@months = (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August);
print @months[-6 .. 0];
print @months[-1 .. 0];
```

The output it gives me is

```
MarchAprilMayJuneJulyAugustJanuary
AugustJanuary
```

But what I want is, it should print out

```
AugustJulyJuneMayAprilMarchFebruaryJanuary
```

Can anyone please help. I am a perl beginner.

Comment: Why "_without using reverse function._"?  Seems pretty arbitrary.

Comment: @zdim its a part of academic exercise, to do so.

Comment: [More techniques from a Google search result](http://www.justskins.com/forums/reverse-range-10-1-a-25966.html)

Comment: @zdim - I'm guessing it's probably homework...

Comment: `print $months[-$_] for 1..@months;`

Comment: @YiminRong  Yeah, they said so ... I like the term "academic exercise" though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@months[-6 .. 0], @months[-1 .. 0]
```

or

```
@months[-6 .. 0, -1 .. 0]
```

means

```
@months[-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, -1, 0]
```

But you want

```
@months[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8]
```

or simply

```
@months[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

---

The obvious solution is

```
reverse(@months)
```

Other expressions that work:

```
@months[ map { -$_ } 1..@months ]

@months[ map { $#months-$_ } 0..$#months ]

map { $months[-$_] } 1..@months

map { $months[ $#months-$_ ] } 0..$#months

use feature qw( current_sub );
sub { @_ ? pop(@_), __SUB__->(@_) : () }->(@months)

do { my @reversed; for my $month (@months) { unshift(@reversed, $month) } @reversed }
```

An in-place solution:

```
for (0..@months/2-1) {
   ($month[$_], $month[-$_-1]) = ($month[-$_-1], $month[$_]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In pseudocode:

```
while array is not empty
    element ← pop from array
    print element
end
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to find the actual names of the functions. ☺

Answer (score 3):

To only "*print the elements*"

```
while (my $mon = pop @months) { say $mon }
```

or

```
say pop @months while @months;
```

Or, as given in a comment by [Сухой27](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B927)

```
print $months[-$_] for 1..@months;
```

---

Original post (contained in the earlier answer by ikegami).

"*Without reverse function*"

```
my @nums = 1..5;

my @rev_ind = map { -$_ + $#nums } 0..$#nums;

print "@nums[@rev_ind]\n";
```

Prints `5 4 3 2 1`

---

Comment: It's ok if answers overlap; you don't need to excuse it :)

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for saying that :)  The 'history' of this was funny though -- I posted (the bottom part only at the time) and then looked up ... and it was right there in your extensive answer! So i deleted it ... I added another piece later

Answer (score 0):

This is another versatile way to work with a variable number of elements, in reverse order, from an array, from the last element to the first one:

```
my @months = (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August);

for (my $i = $#months; $i >= 0; $i--) { 
  print $months[$i];
}
```